# JOIN с условием и без общего идентификатора

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сджойнить 2 таблицы:

### Автомобили

- марка
- мощность

### Категории_автомобиля

- название категории
- мин_мощность

В итоге должно отбираться:
- марка
- название категории

Отбор при условии, что мощность >= мин_мощность в категориях. Все осложняется тем, что если мощность=150, то категория должна быть та, где мин_мощность=120 (но под условие >=150 попадает несколько категорий). Плюс, может быть мощность меньше, чем минимальная мощность в категориях и нужно вернуть пустую строку или нулл.

Теоретически, строк не так много и можно сделать подзапрос для каждой строки, но мне кажется, что это совсем как-то не айс.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (
             select car.mark       /* марка              */ 
                  , car.power      /* мощность           */
                  , cat.cat        /* название категории */
                  , cat.min_power  /* мин_мощность       */
                  , rank() over (partition by car.mark 
                                 order by cat.min_power desc) rnk
             from car      /* Автомобили           */
             left join cat /* Категории_автомобиля */
               on car.power >= cat.min_power
            )
select cte.mark
     , cte.power
     , cte.cat
     , cte.min_power
from cte
where cte.rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Пусть для примера будет следующая база данных

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
  title text,
  power int
);

CREATE TABLE categories (
  title text,
  power int
);

INSERT INTO cars VALUES ('kia', 120), ('kamaz', '1000'), ('bike', 20);
INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('auto', 100), ('truck', 500);
```

`cars` — таблица автомобилей, а `categories` — их типы. `cars.title` — название автомобиля, `cars.title` — мощность, `categories.title` — название категории, а `categories.power` — минимальная мощность для попадания в категорию.

Тогда получить соответствие марки автомобиля и категории можно при помощи следующего запроса

```
SELECT
  cars_power.title AS car,
  categories.title
FROM
  (SELECT
    cars.title,
    MAX(categories.power) AS power_min
  FROM
    cars
  LEFT JOIN
    categories
  ON
    cars.power >= categories.power
  GROUP BY
    cars.title) AS cars_power
LEFT JOIN
  categories
ON
  cars_power.power_min = categories.power;
```

В результате получим

```
  car  | title
-------+-------
 kia   | auto
 kamaz | truck
 bike  |
```

Comment: А как насчёт *может быть мощность меньше, чем минимальная мощность в категориях и нужно вернуть пустую строку или нулл.* ?

Comment: @Akina спасибо за замечание, поправил запрос.